# Pick and choose which modules get browserified

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I have a project where I'm using browserify with node, not on the browser.

I'd like to browserify my project and also make it so that an explicit module can be ignored from the browserify process. Say I'm using `lodash`, `knex` and `bluebird`. I'd like to still use the copy of `knex` that is in in `node_modules`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

[browser field in package.json](https://github.com/defunctzombie/package-browser-field-spec) may help you.

Put something like this into your package.json:

```json
{
  "browser": {
    "knex": "path/to/the-copy-of-knex"
  }
}
```